# Low wifi speed even with 5Ghz wifi adapter

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, hotspot, hostapd

My internet download speed from my D-Link wifi router is *24 M bits/s*

From ethernet the download speed is **50 Mbits/s**

I am using Tp-link AC600 Archer T2U Plus wifi adapter with Rapberry pi 3B+

I tried to use it with 5 Ghz and 2.4 Ghz both. The speed for the adapter is supposed to be **200 Mbps 2.4 Ghz / 433 Mbps on 5 Ghz**.

But even with the 5Ghz I can get only **19 Mbps** download speed when connected to the hotspot. It shows a network speed of **54 Mbps** in my wifi settings whereas the D-link router shows 72 Mbps on the 2.4 Ghz.

Here is my hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=a
channel=48
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

ssid=Wlan1

wpa_passphrase=1234567a
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where's the hotspot, is it on that D-Link router?

Comment: No. On the raspberry pi. D link router has its own WiFi access point

Comment: Then, how is the RPi connected to the Internet and how fast is *that* connection? I suggest you add such details to your question, perhaps draw a diagram showing network links, otherwise you may not get a useful answer despite the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this test](https://notenoughtech.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-internet-speed/) of RPi performance w.r.t various network interfaces. Built-in WiFi on an RPi 3 is capped at 36 Mbps, and a USB dongle is capped at about 80Mbps in ideal conditions. At 10 meters distance, those numbers drop to 32 and 64 Mbps respectively.

After you factor in overhead from **two** interfaces running simultaneously, routing performance losses, delays, etc., 19 Mb/s is actually a quite decent number.

If you need high performance, use a router. Those are optimized for maximum raw Mbps at the expense of other features, so a generic board like Raspberry running a generic Linux distro will never come close to that.

Comment: I am using a 5GHz external adapter. Any reason it should still have low speed? As the USB throughput is not the issue

Comment: @Arahasya There is an unavoidable delay when a data packet is routed from one network interface to the other. Many routers have hardware-accelerated routing pipelines which work on several packets which can be "statelessly" routed in parallel. On the RPi the CPU is used to copy a data buffer from one RAM location to another, and AFAIK this is done on one packet at a time regardless of how complex the routing decision is.

Comment: 5 M Bits or Bytes?

Comment: @Arahasya Anecdotally, I've once made a router out of an Orange Pi Zero. I didn't spend time optimizing it, and the throughput from a straightforward implementation was only 5 Mb/s. For reference, OPi Zero's WiFi is capped at about 15 Mb/s.